# Classic ASP cache busting (& yet still satisfying PageSpeed score)

Tags: caching, iis, asp-classic, pagespeed

**Scenario:**

I am working with IIS and ASP, and we need to cache the site (to make [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/), and my boss, happy). We currently have IIS caching *everything* (asp/JS/CSS) for a period of 1 week.

**Problem:**

After updating the HTML content on the ASP pages, my boss sees the old version of the page until he does a (force) refresh.

**Question:**

How can I (force) update the server cache after I make a change to the ASP HTML content?

I would like my peers and managers to see the latest changes without making them do a forced browser refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Are you configured to use the "If-Modified-Since" HTTP Header?

This explanation on Scott Hanselman's blog gives you and idea of what you are looking for - [Forcing an update of a cached JavaScript file in IIS](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ForcingAnUpdateOfACachedJavaScriptFileInIIS.aspx)

This page also provides a useful primer for the ["If-Modified-Since" HTTP Header](https://varvy.com/ifmodified.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if we can make the boss happy. Like you, I have a few people that think F5 or Ctrl+F5 is annoying.

Quick Review, to be sure your Output Cache on your IIS server is updating on Change let's set it to "**Cache until Change**". 
I read that you clear it every week but if things don't change... Why?
[image]

Let's set the client browser caching defaults. 
And you have the following for all your page headers letting the page expire after 30 minutes using GMT time.
**Master header:**

```
Dim dtmExp
Response.Buffer = True
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
dtmExp = DateAdd("n", 30, Now())
Response.ExpiresAbsolute = dtmExp
Response.Expires = dtmExp
```

We have several options and methods to trigger our header change. 
You can use Sessions, Cookies, DB updates etc. in this example I'm using Sessions feel free to change things around to fit your application better.

PageEdit.asp

```
    Session("EditedPageFullURL") = "/yourpage.asp"
```

In a common functions page add the following.

```
Function EditorsReload(eChk,erURL)
If IsNumeric(eChk) Then
    Session("Editing") = eChk
End If
If Len(erURL) = 0 Then
    Exit Function
End If
If Session("Editing") <> "" Then
    If Session("Editing") = 1 Then
        If (LCase(erURL) = LCase(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))) Then
            Session("Editing") = ""
            Session("EditedPageFullURL") = ""
            Response.Expires = -1
            Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now() -1 
            Response.AddHeader "pragma", "no-store"
            Response.AddHeader "cache-control","no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" 
      End If 
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Place the following in your page just below any headers you might have.

```
Call EditorsReload(1,Session("EditedPageFullURL"))
```

You can wrap it in a "Session("AUTH")" if your site has login and member sessions setup. 
Other than that, this will fire only when Session("EditedPageFullRUL" has a length greater than 1.

This will update the bosses browser header forcing the browser to refresh the local cache. 
It is a one time deal so any additional page refresh is using the standard headers.

There are many ways of doing this so be creative!